# Align infobox to marker in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, gmaps4rails, marker, infowindow

I am using the InfoBox plugin, and I have the following code:

```
Gmaps.map.infobox = function(boxText) {
  return {
     content: boxText
    ,disableAutoPan: false
    ,maxWidth: 0
    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
    ,zIndex: null
    ,boxStyle: {
      background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
      ,opacity: 0.75
      ,width: "280px"
       }
    ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
    ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
    ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
    ,isHidden: false
    ,pane: "floatPane"
    ,enableEventPropagation: false
 }};
```

With a marker of dimensions 77x80 pixels, when the InfoWindow is shown, it aligns correctly at the bottom of the marker, as you can see here:

[image: Big Marker with Infobox well aligned]

However, if I change the size of the marker to 35x44 px, the InfoWindow is not exactly aligned at the bottom of the marker, as you can see here:

[image: Small Marker with Infobox wrong aligned]

Any thoughts on how can I make it completely aligned at the bottom?

EDIT: For the small markers,  I created them by setting this in the library I use (gmaps4rails):

```
marker.picture({
                  :picture => "assets/juice-pin-small.png",
                  :width => 35,
                  :height => 44,
                 })
```

For the big markers, I create them by setting this:

```
marker.picture({
                      :picture => "assets/juice-pin-small.png",
                      :width => 70,
                      :height => 88,
                      :marker_anchor => [23,78]
                     })
```

Comment: Could you add the full definitions of both markers as well, rather than just mention the size? And how are you adding the infoBox to the map?

Comment: What do you mean by full definition? I have edited with what do I set in the library...I add the infobox, by adding what I have said in the question in between <script> tags after the map has been generated by the library.

Comment: Because if the infoBox is attached to the marker with something like  `infobox.open(map, marker);` it depends on the marker definition. And that may not be in the right place either if its anchor is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know is definitely not the best solution, because you need two sets of options if you will use both sized markers.

Anyway, the positioning of the infobox can be changed with `pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0);`, in your case, to move the box left, make the first number more negative (like, -145).

Thought of something else: edit the marker itself and shift it a few pixels.